# Retrieving Pycharm output

Tags: pycharm, output

I ran a number randomizer algorithm in pycharm but I closed the run window by mistake after the code finished running, is there anyway I can retrieve that data, i really need it and there is no possibility of rerunning the code with the same result. I'd be really grateful if anyone could help, thank you!

I didnt keep logs or any sort of failsafe and I can't find anything in history.

Comment: I highly doubt that restoring data is possible. Unless it's in some cache of recent data or temporary files.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to check that?

Comment: use a search app (grep or np++) to search for it in the project folder, if there is a certain keyword that gets printed then you can use it to know whether it was saved or not.

Comment: It's vital to know if you used the python console or not? Did you run your code like this: `'python3 main.py'` or did you just press the 'run' button? Either way.. You shouldn't have much hope.. It does seem very unlikely that anything can be restored, especially if you closed the IDE.

Comment: I ran the python file, I didn't press the button. Maybe it's worth a mention that I didn't close pycharm entirely, just the output window. I tried looking through the temporary files but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Do you have any temporary files generated in your project directory? Check Python Console: There is a history button (but I think it only works for commands). You can dig into `View > Tool Windows` and try out what you can see. If nothing works (which I suspect), try contacting the pycharm [support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-tips-of-the-day.html) and DON'T close the editor. Also you might want to filter with grep as mentioned earlier.

Comment: The only temp files I have are from a few weeks ago unfortunately. I've written to support, thank you for the advice and your time, really appreciate it!